# How to ensure ExtJS Datepicker shows up completely?

Tags: javascript, extjs

When the Date Picker is rendered on click, it is clipped and I can't get it to show up completely:

[image: Clipped Date Picker]

While defining the datefield xtype, I have tried tweaking a few config options like cls,baseBodyCls,componentCls, etc. to tweak the overflow-y/height property by setting them to auto, but nothing seems to work. What should I try?

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with pickerAlign:

```
xtype:'datefield',
pickerAlign:'bl-tl?'
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Picker-cfg-pickerAlign

Comment: I tried that. Alignment is not the problem. Layout is, if I understand correctly.